# Validate string with custom regex

Tags: android, regex

Im trying to validate some strings with custom Regex expressions. I have the follwing method to do so:

```
    public static boolean validateWithCustomRegex(String pattern,String toValidate){
    boolean result = false;

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(toValidate);
    if (m.find())
        result=true;

    return result;
}
```

**EDIT**
I get my regex in a json array with objects i get from an API

```
{

"ParamCd":"testeUrl",
"ParamVldtnRgExp":"@\\b((ftp|https?):\/\/[-\\w]+(\\.\\w[-\\w]*)+|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+(?: com\\b|edu\\b|biz\\b|gov\\b|in(?:t|fo)\\b|mil\\b|net\\b|org\\b|[a-z][a-z]\\b))(\\:\\d+)?(\/[^.!,?;\"'<>()\\[\\]{}\\s\\x7F-\\xFF]*(?:[.!,?]+[^.!,?;\"'<>()\\[\\]{}\\s\\x7F-\\xFF]+)*)?@iS",
"ParamWbCntrlCd":"TEXTBOX",
"ParamOrdr":1053,
"UsrCnfgrblPrmtrsRspnItms":[
    {
        "LangCd":"pt-PT",
        "LablTxt":"xxxxxx",
        "HlprTxt":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ErrTxt":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
        "LangCd":"en-UK",
        "LablTxt":"xxxxxx",
        "HlprTxt":"xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "ErrTxt":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
]

}
```

And my pattern is:

```
@\b((ftp|https?)://[-\w]+(\.\w[-\w]*)+|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?: com\b|edu\b|biz\b|gov\b|in(?:t|fo)\b|mil\b|net\b|org\b|[a-z][a-z]\b))(\:\d+)?(/[^.!,?;"'<>()\[\]{}\s\x7F-\xFF]*(?:[.!,?]+[^.!,?;"'<>()\[\]{}\s\x7F-\xFF]+)*)?@iS
```

and my "toValidate" string is: `http://s.com`

In this website the regex validates my string
https://regex101.com/r/kD4nNJ/1 
but on Android im always getting "`false`"

Is my method wrong?

Comment: "And my pattern is" -- where is this? Is this in a Java `static` field? Is this in a string resource? Is it somewhere else? My concern is that you may not have properly escaped this value, and the escaping rules will vary depending upon where this value exists in your app.

Comment: I get it from a Json response from an api

Comment: The JSON response is giving you the regular expression pattern? Also note that your link is to a site that is testing PHP regex syntax. You are not programming in PHP here. Using [a Java regex site](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), your regex does not work with your test data.

Comment: @CommonsWare, ah , dind't noticed it was for PHP. I added an example of the json i get from the API, its an array with objects like those.

Comment: `\b((ftp|https?)://[-\w]+(\.\w[-\w]*)+|(?:[a-z0-9](?:[-a-z0-9]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:(?: com|edu|biz|gov|in(?:t|fo)|mil|net|org)\b|[a-z]{2}\b))(\:\d+)?(/[^.!,?;"'<>()\[\]{}\s\x7F-\xFF]*(?:[.!,?]+[^.!,?;"'<>()\[\]{}\s\x7F-\xFF]+)*)?` is slightly shorter. Also, your delimiters seem to be `@`, not sure that's supported in Java. I don't think delimiters even matter in Java, so it may interpret those `@` literally (along with `iS` flags). Also what's the `S` modifer? I know `s` is single line, but I've never seen `S`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to validate a url

```
android.util.Patterns.WEB_URL.matcher(url).matches();
```

Comment: The problem is i get other kinds of Regexs that validate other things besides urls

Answer (score 0):

First, talk to the developers of the Web service, or read its documentation, and see what the specifications are for `ParamVldtnRgExp`. Since it works with a PCRE (PHP) regex tester and does not work with Java, *probably* the expressions are in PCRE format, but it would be good to confirm that with the people that are publishing this data.

Then, there are three main options:

1. Find a PCRE-compatible regex library for Java
2. Come up with a way to convert PCRE expressions into valid Java ones
3. Convince the developers of the Web service to serve up some other regex pattern format, whether Java's or one for which you can find a suitable library